# Hyperparameter optimization with random search

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter, optimization

I would like to do a random search for hyperparameter optimization. The procedure can be found in [link](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf). One possibility is to define a fine grid and take random combinations. A better approach would be to define a distribution for each parameter.

I'm thinking about optimizing SVM with parameters C and gamma (RBF kernel) and also k-nearest neighbours. Of course C and gamma are continuous while k is discrete.

What distributions can be choosen for C, gamma and k?

Second, let's assume a random search optimization over parameters which have to sum to one. How could one incorporate this constraint into the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What distributions can be choosen for C, gamma and k?

To reproduce results from other methods, define a box and sample uniformly in the box. This will parallel the procedure of grid search, or any other tuning method, since each point is equally likely *a priori*.

But if you want some distributions more informative than these, then you'll have to work that out for the problem at hand because that is inherently a context-dependent question: some problems have larger/smaller $\gamma$ and $C$ than others, which is why we tune hyper-parameters in the first place.

If you decide to make this a fully Bayesian problem with informative probabilities over hyper-parameters, embedding the problem as a logistic regression can create a direct path to probability models.

> Second, let's assume a random search optimization over parameters which have to sum to one. How could one incorporate this constraint into the search?

[Use a stick-breaking process](http://www.columbia.edu/~jwp2128/Teaching/E6892/papers/SimpleProof.pdf). You start with a unit interval, and pick a point in the interval according to a probabiltiy distribution over the unit interval. Then you iterate $k-1$ times the process for the interval "to the right" (or left) of the chosen point. At the end, you'll have $k$ value which sum to 1.

You could also review the [stan documentation](http://mc-stan.org/documentation/) pertaining to sampling of simplex random variables for an alternative presentation of the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's say I have a box [1,10]. How can I sample uniformly from it (e.g. using Matlab)? Should I just generate a random number between [1,10]?

Comment: Regarding the stick-breaking process: Let's assume I have an initial interval of [0,1] and I pick the value 0.7 at random for the first value. So we now that only 0.3 remains for the other values, so I sample from [0,0.3] for the second value. Let's say the second value gets a value of 0.2, so the third value will be sampled from [0,0.1]. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Don't know how to do it in Matlab.

Comment: @BlackHawk but note the relationship between the Dirichlet distribution and simplex-valued random variables.

Comment: What role does this relationship play here?

Comment: The Dirichlet is a probability distribution over the unit simplex.

Comment: Ok, but how can this be of use here?

Comment: Shouldn't I use the stick-breaking process described above and instead using the dirichlet? I don't see how I could use the Dirichlet here. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Depends on what you need. The output of a Dirichlet psuedo random number generator is a simplex draw from the appropriate distribution. The stick-breaking process just gives some intervals, not necessarily from the desired distribution (because it's unclear what the desired distribution is here).

Comment: Ah I see. So let me explain. I'm using a SVM classifier with a weighted RBF kernel. My dataset has 17 features. In the RBF kernel I will use a weight for each feature. Of course the weights must sum to one. Would you use in this case the stick-breaking process or the Dirichlet pseudo random number generator? There is also the question if I should vary the weights only around 1/17 (e.g. with a normal distribution) or if I should allow some few weights to become very large and the others very small.

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question.

Comment: I have created a new question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211275/how-to-sample-weights-for-weighted-kernels I would highly appreciate if you could take a look.

Answer (score 3):

There are full bayesian formulations for SVMs. Why not using those?. In the case of SVM you may consider [Relevance Vector Machines](http://www.miketipping.com/sparsebayes.htm).

kNN is not bayesian, and independent of the underlying probability distribution. How to define a prior then?.

Bayesian models are generative models, that is, they model a complete pdf from which the data is supposed to be sampled from. Therefore, I find it would be more natural to consider GMM or some other more [modern non-parametric technique](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/294-fall09/lectures/nonparametric/slides.pdf). The question becomes then on how to determine the optimal number of components. The standard way is to sample from a Dirichlet prior, and then sample from the particular mixture obtained from it.

Answer (score -1):

You are basically describing a Bayesian Optimization (updating the distributions of parameters as you observe fitness values). The [GPyOpt](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPyOpt/blob/540fda8344a936ed315b9a929afddacbc8adf6f9/manual/tutorial/CourseBO_Lab3.ipynb) devel branch has a tutorial on how to fit SVM with it.
Constraints should be relatively straightforward to add.

However, all this might be an overkill. If you are simply interested in how search might improve fitting you might just as well start simple with something like a genetic algorithm.

Comment: Where does OP suggest updating his parameter distributions after observing fitness?

Comment: you are doing a search. As you get results from your search (in terms of statistical loss for example) you want to update the distribution from where you sample hyper-parameters so that it's more likely the next hyper-parameters are good. Bayesian optimization simply involves updating the original distribution from where you were sampling hyper-parameters to guide search onto promising areas. I suppose you don't HAVE to, but there is no real reason not to run efficient search.

Comment: I understand what Bayesian Optimization is, but my point is that OP is not necessarily asking about BO. In fact, OP is explicitly asking about **random search** methods, as he explicitly names this method. We can directly contrast random search to BO because BO incorporates information about the objective function while random search does not, so BO is not an answer to OP's question (even if it may be superior to random search).

Comment: Sure, fair enough. It seems to me however that if the question pertains the choice of distributions to sample from it is just natural to suggest using a methodology that discover such distribution on its own. Moreover since the final aim of the question is fitting SVMs then providing, as I did, a link to a tutorial showing the passages will do wonder. Perhaps this might still be an overkill but surely it can't really hurt or deserve the opprobrium it generated.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with python. Do you know a similar tutorial for Matlab or Java?

Comment: mloss http://mloss.org/software/view/453/ and bayesopt http://rmcantin.bitbucket.org/html/ are on matlab and they have tutorials but not specific to SVM fitting unfortunately.